# How to change UIImageview image by clicking on that image instead of button click in Iphone?

Tags: uiimageview

How to change image by click on that image in Iphone.Instead of button click I want to click on image.Which method can I use UIImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Use a button and make your picture the picture for the button. You can do all this in Storyboard and then right click the button and drag to the view you want to go to. It should work just like that.

After you drag the button to the storyboard go to the property inspector. Make the button a custom button in the drop down list and then use the image field to select your image. You will need to size the button correctly and set the fill property to "size to fit." the other button behaviors are all customizable if you don't want normal button behavior, i.e. visually reacting to a touch.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `tapRecognizer` for your `ImageView`. It'll detect tap on your `ImageView` and call the method `-clickEventOnImage`.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(clickEventOnImage:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
//Don't forget to set the userInteractionEnabled to YES, by default It's NO.
myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[myImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Add your `clickEventOnImage:` will look like this :

```
-(void) clickEventOnImage:(id) sender
{
    [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"myNewImageName.png"]];
}
```

Comment: Can I push into another view with in the method using push view controller?

Comment: @user2420691 : yeah, sure. Why not ?

Comment: How to set tapRecognizer for ImageView

Comment: @user2420691 : That I already mentioned in 1st portion of my Answer. You just have to add that navigation code in that `-clickEventOnImage` method.

Comment: @user2420691 : Inside `-(void) clickEventOnImage:(id) sender`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using touchevents also

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([[touches anyObject] view] == self.m_ImageViewObjectName) {
        //Here you can change the image of UIImageView
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I push into another view with in the method using push view controller?

Comment: Just insert the code to push where i have insert a comment it will be pushed

Comment: But it not navigated into next screen the below is my code                                                       -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([[touches anyObject] view] == self.imageView) {
        AddProfileViewController *Dvc = [[AddProfileViewController alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:Dvc animated:YES];
            }
}

Comment: Why we are using if statement,I removed if statement it's working fine

Comment: So it is working for you? The thing about if statement is if we are using touch event on any other object also so it could make you perform different tasks just via touch